# How to apply the same function to different objects

Tags: javascript, function

I'm wondering if there's a way for me to make different divs perform the same task in a function when they're clicked on. Here's what I have so far. When I run this code, however, nothing seems to happen but I also don't see any errors. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="works">
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></div>
</div>
<div class = "image">
  <img class = "phone" src = "img/phone.png">
  <div class = "ad _0"></div>
  <div class = "ad _1"></div>
  <div class = "ad _2"></div>
  <div class = "ad _3"></div>
</div>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var slideIndex = 0,
frames =[80,154,64,49],
counters = [0,0,0,0];

showSlides(slideIndex);

function animation(ad, frames, counter) {
    if (counter < frames){
        position = counter * (100/frames);
        $(ad).css({"background-position": position + "% 0%"});
        counter ++;
    } else {
        counter = 0;
    }
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    $("._" + i).css({"visibility": "hidden"});
  }
  $("._" + slideIndex).css({"visibility": "visible"});
  setInterval(animation("._" + slideIndex, frames[slideIndex], counters[slideIndex]),150);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I plug in the parameters directly into the animation function, like below:

```
function animation() {
  var counter = counters[0];
  if (counter < 80){
    position = counter * (100/80);
    $("._0").css({"background-position": position + "% 0%"});
    counters[0]++;
  } else {
    counters[0] = 0;
  }
}
```

and call the function like so:

```
setInterval(animation,150);
```

I get the result I want but I don't want to have to manually plug in each parameter :\

Comment: *nothing seems to happen* — what do you expect to happen?

Comment: basically, it's suppose to pan across each image giving the illusion that it's animating.

Comment: in your code `slideIndex` always `=0`. I think in last function `showSlides` you need to change argument name from `n` to `slideIndex` or use `n` inside function instead `slideIndex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function() {
  animation("._" + slideIndex, frames[slideIndex], counters[slideIndex])
}, 150);
```

**Problem:**
Your original code
`setInterval(animation("._" + slideIndex, frames[slideIndex], counters[slideIndex]),150);` calls the function `animation` and passes the result to `setInterval`. You need to pass *a function that calls* `animation` by wrapping it in  a function expression.

**Why no errors?**
If you pass a non-function to `setInterval`, it fails silently on many browsers.

EDIT: Thanks @user2724072 for posting full code. See the code below for (hopefully) a fix. Also, if nothing happens, it might be because of your css code. I cloned the code on jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/uLq5nry5/3/, and changed the code to switch `ad` to different color.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="works">
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></div>
</div>
<div class = "image">
  <img class = "phone" src = "img/phone.png">
  <div class = "ad x0"></div>
  <div class = "ad x1"></div>
  <div class = "ad x2"></div>
  <div class = "ad x3"></div>
</div>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var slideIndex = 0,
frames =[80,154,64,49],
counters = [0,0,0,0];

showSlides(slideIndex);

function animation(ad, frames, counterIndex) {
    var counter = counters[counterIndex];
    if (counter < frames){
        position = counter * (100/frames);
        $(ad).css({"background-position": position + "% 0%"});
        counters[counterIndex]++;
    } else {
        counter[counterIndex] = 0;
    }
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    $(".x" + i).css({"visibility": "hidden"});
  }
  $(".x" + slideIndex).css({"visibility": "visible"});
  setInterval(animation(".x" + slideIndex, frames[slideIndex], slideIndex),150);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Changes:**
`animation()` now takes a `counterIndex` parameter instead of a `counter` parameter.
Also, classes with '_*n*' are replaced with 'x*n*'. Underscore classnames have weird quirks when it comes to browser compatibility.

**Why:**
Javascript doesn't have "pointers" like C, so `var counter = counters[i]; counter++;` won't change the value of `counters[i]`.

Comment: Hey Kyle, thanks for the response. I implemented this solution and I'm still not coming up with anything. I'm not sure why :\

Comment: Could you please share the rest of your code? It would help the debugging process a lot. I'm not sure how these functions are being applied.

Comment: Thanks! The first error I found is with the `counter` parameter in your `animation()` function. When you modify `counter`, it only modifies the variable for the scope of the `animation` function. The `counters` array is unchanged, so when you call it in `setInterval(function() {
  animation("._" + slideIndex, frames[slideIndex], counters[slideIndex])
}, 150);`, `counters[slideIndex]` is always the same.

Comment: thanks for all your work! i implemented your solution but the only problem is that now, although there is animation, it's triggered once, every time the dot that corresponds to each sprite image is clicked. what i was hoping for, however, was that the dot only needs to be clicked once to trigger the animation function for each image sprite. so, if the first dot is clicked once,  ad x0, which has 80 frames, will be fed into the animation function. does that make sense?

Comment: i made a slight adjustment to your code by calling the animation function inside another function within setInterval and now it works!! the only problem now is that every time i click on another dot, the interval rate seems to decrease making the animation too fast haha

Answer (score 0):

**UPD** Look at the snippet blow..

I thik in your code `slideIndex` always `=0`. In last function `showSlides` you need to change argument name from `n` to `slideIndex` or use `n` inside function instead `slideIndex`

Try this way:

```js
var slideIndex = 0,
frames =[80,154,64,49],
counters = [0,0,0,0];

showSlides(slideIndex);

function animation(ad, frames, counter) {
    if (counter < frames){
        position = counter * (100/frames);
        $(ad).css({"background-position": position + "% 0%"});
        counter ++;
    } else {
        counter = 0;
    }
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(n);
}

function showSlides(slideIndex) {
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    $("._" + i).css({"visibility": "hidden"});
  }
  $("._" + slideIndex).css({"visibility": "visible"});
}


var TOTAL = 4; //quatity of slides
var currentGlobalIndex = 0; //number of first slide

var nextSlideIndexFor = function(globalCounter){
  return globalCounter%TOTAL;
}

setInterval(function(){
  var nextSlideIndex = nextSlideIndexFor(currentGlobalIndex++);
  
  animation("._" + nextSlideIndex, frames[nextSlideIndex], counters[nextSlideIndex])
  
  console.log("show slide number" + nextSlideIndex);
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="works">
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></div>
</div>
<div class = "image">
  <img class = "phone" src = "img/phone.png">
  <div class = "ad _0"></div>
  <div class = "ad _1"></div>
  <div class = "ad _2"></div>
  <div class = "ad _3"></div>
</div>
```